# Decode user input by index position

Tags: c#, string, input

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    int number = 0;
    int powerOfFive = 1;

    const string coders = " 0Oo1l";
    const int five = 5;

    for (int i = text.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int decodedDigit = coders.IndexOf(text[i]);
        number += powerOfFive * decodedDigit;
        powerOfFive *= five;
    }

    Console.Write(number);
}
```

For input data:

```
11 ll 00 O OO oO o 10
```

The console will display:

```
24 30 6 2 12 17 3 21
```

In my code I can only take one pair of characters (except the case when there are single character) separated by a space at one input at a time.

How can I take the entire string in one input?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, instead of asking for user input, make the input string hard coded in the program.

Comment: How is the code supposed to work? What is the power of 5 stuff for?

Comment: We read the list of coded numbers from the keyboard and for each coded number we execute:

1. We initialize the decoded number with 0.
2. We initialize a variable powerOfFive with 1 (5 to the power of 0).
3. For each character in the coded number starting from the last one we execute:

we declare a decodedDigit variable that we initialize with the value corresponding to the current character (1 for 0, 2 for O, 3 for o, 4 for 1, 5 for l)
to the decoded number we add powerOfFive * decodedDigit
we multiply powerOfFive by 5

Comment: Are you sure about that output? I have a possible answer, but my code outputs `24 30 6 2 12 17 3 21`. Same as the expected output except the last one is `21` not `2`....Oh, well going to lunch. Will post answer anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's 21 the last output number! My mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are supposed to split the input string on space and then process each substring individually.

```
string text = Console.ReadLine();

const string coders = " 0Oo1l";
const int five = 5;

foreach (var code in text.Split(' '))
{
    int number = 0;
    int powerOfFive = 1;
    for (int i = code.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        int decodedDigit = coders.IndexOf(code[i]);
        number += powerOfFive * decodedDigit;
        powerOfFive *= five;
    }
    Console.Write(number + " ");
}
```

Sample input/output:

```
11 ll 00 O OO oO o 10
24 30 6 2 12 17 3 21
```

Comment: You were right, the last number is 21.

Thank you!